# Which Gazebo versions Supported for Ubuntu 22.04(Jammy)

Tags: gazebo-11, gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am using Ubuntu 22.04. Because laptop has AMD RX5600m GPU therefore other Ubuntu versions throws many error for GPU.

I've tried installing gazebo (gazebo9 - gazebo11) but I am getting the below mentioned error. Maybe Gazebo9 or 11 not supported Jammy.

ERROR is:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done

N: Ignoring file 'gazebo-stable.listwget' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

E: Unable to locate package gazebo11

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28083/which-gazebo-versions-supported-for-ubuntu-22.04(jammy)/) by [zHarunz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/84949/zharunz/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2022-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

You can see all the supported platforms for Gazebo classic here:

https://classic.gazebosim.org/#status

Gazebo 9 is only officially supported up to Ubuntu Bionic, and Gazebo 11 only up to Ubuntu Focal.

You'll notice that Gazebo 11 is an official package on Ubuntu Jammy though:

https://packages.ubuntu.com/cs/jammy/science/gazebo

Just do

`sudo apt install gazebo`

As with any official package, that won't be getting new features nor minor bugfixes.

You may also be able to compile Gazebo 11 from source on Jammy, but we're not actively maintaining that. If something is broken, we'll review pull requests from the community though.

---

For completeness, I'll mention that we also have [Gazebo Fortress upstream on Ubuntu Jammy](https://packages.ubuntu.com/cs/jammy/libignition-gazebo-dev), just do:

`sudo apt install libignition-gazebo-dev ignition-tools`

Unlike Gazebo 11, Fortress is officially supported on Jammy and we release binaries with new features and bugfixes into http://packages.osrfoundation.org/ and http://packages.ros.org/.

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2022-05-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljaniec](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/62948/ljaniec/) on 2022-11-14**:
This solution with `sudo apt install gazebo` doesn't work for me (https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/28361/how-to-install-gazebo-for-ubuntu-2204-with-ros2-humble/) because of unmet dependencies:
`gazebo : Depends: libgazebo11 (= 11.10.2+dfsg-1) but 11.12.0-1~focal is to be installed`.
Should I try to build it from source?